# Cancel other promise execution on Promise.race reject

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, cancellation

I am developing an asynchronous Node.js app that implements `Promise.race` for a portion of its logic:

```
async function callDeobfuscator(ast) {
  const withTimeout = (promise) => {
    let timeoutPid;
    const timeoutPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
      timeoutPid = setTimeout(reject, timeout));
    return Promise.race([
        promise,
        timeoutPromise
    ]).finally(() => {
        if (timeoutPid) {
          clearTimeout(timeoutPid);
        }
    });
  };
  return withTimeout(processSource(ast));
};
```

The issue is, `processSource(ast)` may run indefinitely/forever and I want to be able to **cancel** its execution once it times out. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There's no cancellation built in to Promises – you'll need to implement something like https://gist.github.com/danharper/ad6ca574184589dea28d yourself.

Comment: I don't suppose you mean `processSource(ast)` will run indefinitely, because then `withTimeout` would not even be called. You mean the promise it returns may never resolve? If `processSource(ast)` queues asynchronous JS to execute which will do the same itself (infinite asynchronous loop), then you need to implement a time-out mechanism in *that* code.

Comment: Yes I mean the promise it returns may never resolve. Ok so I need to implement the timeout mechanism in that code and not on the original one. Makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Really you should change the code of `processSource` to always settle the returned promise. It should never run infinitely. Reject with an error if you cannot produce a result (in due time). Pass a `CancelSignal`, and repeatedly check it (e.g. by calling `signal.throwIfAborted()`) during the processing. You can then easily pass an [`AbortSignal.timeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/timeout_static).